# Using SQL function as a group by field in datamapper (ruby)

Tags: ruby, group-by, aggregate, datamapper

I'm trying to use a slightly more interesting GROUP BY cause than what seems to be supported out of the box by DataMapper.

The query I want to generate looks something like this:

`SELECT SUM(downloads), SUM(uploads) FROM daily_stats GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date)`

I'd like to be able to just tell DataMapper something along these lines:

`DailyStat.aggregate(:downloads.sum, :uploads.sum, :fields => [ :date.yearweek ])`

Where would I begin? Is this easily achievable?

Answer (score 3):

I would very much like the same thing, unfortunately dm-aggregates isn't written in a manner which makes this possible.

My recommendation is to drop down into SQL since you're receiving sums from your table.

```
DataMapper.repository.adapter.select('SELECT SUM(downloads), SUM(uploads) FROM daily_stats GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date)')
```

That should give you an array of structs with the summed downloads and uploads.